# DateTime.ParseExact - Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using this code, to parse my date:

DateTime.ParseExact(someElement.Attribute("date").Value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss CEST yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

the "date" attribute is equal to: Fri Nov 02 16:30:00 CET 2012

But I still get this error, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `CEST` in your format string, but `CST` in your actual date attribute.